# jquery handle if multiple time click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to do own slider animation of my webpage on my own js code using jquery library,I have one function, in that function i wrote move dom element using animation method with set parameter which element want animate, its working good when calling automatic repeat using setInterval, but if click next or prev button continuously on multiple time, it calling slide function continually how much time i click, so continuously calling method, collapse the css and dom elements that is making my slider ugly :(, kindly help me how can i prevent that issue, I am trying search and get that solution , but i can't get solution, Kindly help needful

click event :

```
$(".health-plan-slider .next").stop().click( function(){

            var ele_n = $(".health-plan-slider .next").attr("data-next");
            slideEffectNext( ele_n );


        });
```

function :

```
function slideEffectNext(dataVal)
    {
        dataVal = parseInt(dataVal);
        var dataValPrev = parseInt(dataVal) - 1;
        if( dataVal == ele_len-1 )
        {
            $(".health-plan-slider .next").attr("data-next",0);
        }
        else
        {
            $(".health-plan-slider .next").attr("data-next", dataVal+1);
        }
        if( dataVal == 0 )
        {
            $(".health-plan-slider .prev").attr("data-prev", ele_len-1);
        }
        else
        {
            $(".health-plan-slider .prev").attr("data-prev", dataVal-1);
        }
        $(".slider-wrap .slide-elements").removeAttr("data-cur");
        $(".slider-wrap .slide-elements").eq(dataVal).css("left", "920px");
        $(".slider-wrap .slide-elements").eq(dataValPrev).animate({ left:-920+"px"}, 1000, function() { $(".slider-wrap .slide-elements").eq(dataValPrev).css("left",920+"px");});
        $(".slider-wrap .slide-elements").eq(dataVal).animate({ left:0+"px"}, 1000).attr("data-cur", 1);
    }
```

Advance thanks

Comment: where's your code!!!

Comment: Post you working code.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.stop()
```

to stop animation each time you click next or prev

```
$('#next').stop().click(function() {
    // your animation ..
})
```

same for $('#prev')

Answer (score 1):

try this logic

```
$(".health-plan-slider .next").click( function(){
    if(typeof sliding != "undefined" && sliding){
        var ele_n = $(".health-plan-slider .next").attr("data-next");
        slideEffectNext( ele_n );
    }
});


function slideEffectNext(dataVal){
    sliding = true;
    dataVal = parseInt(dataVal);
    var dataValPrev = parseInt(dataVal) - 1;
    if( dataVal == ele_len-1 )
    {
        $(".health-plan-slider .next").attr("data-next",0);
    }
    else
    {
        $(".health-plan-slider .next").attr("data-next", dataVal+1);
    }
    if( dataVal == 0 )
    {
        $(".health-plan-slider .prev").attr("data-prev", ele_len-1);
    }
    else
    {
        $(".health-plan-slider .prev").attr("data-prev", dataVal-1);
    }
    $(".slider-wrap .slide-elements").removeAttr("data-cur");
    $(".slider-wrap .slide-elements").eq(dataVal).css("left", "920px");
    $(".slider-wrap .slide-elements").eq(dataValPrev).animate({ left:-920+"px"}, 1000, function() { $(".slider-wrap .slide-elements").eq(dataValPrev).css("left",920+"px");});
    $(".slider-wrap .slide-elements").eq(dataVal).animate({ left:0+"px"}, 1000,function(){sliding = false;}).attr("data-cur", 1);
}
```